# Jetty thread pool embeddend in Apache CXF

Tags: java, cxf, embedded-jetty

I'm handling the code written by third parties (it is a standalone software), and I've found a code section which is not clear to me:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean restFactory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
for (int index=0; index<resourceClasses.size(); index++) {
    restFactory.setResourceClasses(resourceClasses.get(index));
}
restFactory.setAddress(restServerUrl + restBasePath);
server = restFactory.create();
```

By the way is instantiated an Apache CXF 3.1.2 server based on Jetty, but I can not find in the documentation information about which "default" configuration is used by Jetty.

Another need is to change the configuration of Jetty (setting the parameters for the threadpool), but again I do not know how to intervene (I tried to define a beans.xml but apparently it is not read).

Comment: have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Karaf container as explained in the [**discussion link**](http://users.cxf.apache.narkive.com/VM6jalOb/no-bean-named-cxf-is-defined-when-trying-to-configure-jetty) you can configure the pool just by adding a *.cfg file.

Ex:

**File to be added :** $KARAF_HOME/etc/org.apache.cxf.http.jetty-8017.cfg

**File content:**

```
port=8017

threadingParameters.minThreads=10

threadingParameters.maxThreads=50
```